# How to find the path of a directory

Tags: c#, io

Some guys and I have the same folder stored in our C drives, but each in a different location.  I'm trying to write the code that can access to this folder on every machine.  I've tried `"~/xx/xx"`, but it doesn't work.  How should I do this?

**Update:**
This is what I have now:

```
foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\", "*dataDir*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
     Debug.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

Exception: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\$INPLACE.~TR\' is denied.`

Comment: It's probably easier just to make a list of where everyone has the folder stored, or just store the folder in the same place.

Comment: you may explain a bit more... give us an exmaple

Comment: *"the same folder [...] in a different location"* - Then it's a different folder.  You'll have to give us more information about the folder structure, how it's common between the machines, and how you're actually trying to access it.  In general your software should be using relative paths so that it can run in any sub-folder, provided that the application's folder structure remains the same.

Comment: Do you mean like, one guy has `C:\ProgramFiles\STUFF` and another has `C:\Users\Bob\STUFF`, and you want to find the `STUFF` folder no matter where it is?

Comment: Yes, DGH explained the scenario.

Comment: Put the directory in a config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Directory.EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx) should work.  You can do `.Single()` if you're only expecting one match.

```
foreach(var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\", "*STUFF*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

```
Yields:
C:\STUFF
C:\other\STUFF
```

Comment: When I tried the code above, I kept running into directories I don't have access to.  How to work around this?  And is it helpful knowing a section of the path of the folder I'm looking for (`\aa\bb\STUFF`)?  This section of the path is the same on every machine.

Comment: @user1486691: This is throwing an exception for directories you don't have access to or do you just not have access to what it returns?

Comment: For the directories I don't have access to.

Comment: @user1486691:  Will you edit your question to include the code you're using _and_ include the exception text?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this example in [Directory.GetDirectories Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Test 
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
       try 
       {
           // Only get subdirectories that begin with the letter "p." 
           string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "p*");
           Console.WriteLine("The number of directories starting with p is {0}.", dirs.Length);
           foreach (string dir in dirs) 
           {
               Console.WriteLine(dir);
           }
       } 
       catch (Exception e) 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
       }
   }
```

}